# How to install an extension to a browser without confirm

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

When the users enters to a web page, is there a way to install a extension witout confirmation?

in what browser I can do that?, or any links to articles about that?

the keyword is "without confirmation"

Comment: Seriously? Why would any browser allow you to do that?

Comment: While it's a great convenience to not have to have the user confirm, this would allow a lot of malicious extensions.

Answer (score 0):

That wouldn't be possible. Not to mention, it isn't legally or ethically correct. (Just saying)

Answer (score 0):

This is not and should not be possible - and for a good reason.  While your intentions may be genuinely pure, it would open a lot of security loop holes for those wanting to have a bit of "fun."

Here are a couple good sites that explain the damage malicious extensions and toolbars can do:

1. [Bull Guard](http://www.bullguard.com/bullguard-security-center/internet-security/internet-threats/rogue-browser-extensions.aspx)
2. [Symantec](http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/bho-and-xpcom-extensions-gone-wild)